# How to read from stdin and write to stdout of WindowsProcess in Pharo/Squeak?

Tags: stdout, stdin, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I found a way how to run a command in **Windows 10** asynchronously and now I am trying to communicate with it via its stdin, stdout. I did it from Python - I ran python.exe process, sent it a string like "print(1+9)" and got a result - "10". So, now I am trying to repeat this simple task in Pharo or Squeak:

```
p := WindowsProcess command: 'c:\python38\python.exe'.

a := p accessor.

in := a getStdIn.
out := a getStdOut.

inHnd := a getStdInHandle.
outHnd := a getStdOutHandle.
```

So, the next question is - what to do with `in`, `out`, `inHnd`, `outHnd`? My feeling is that I can read/write from/to them, but I get exceptions that `in`, `inHnd` - they are `ByteArray`, so no way to call something like `nextPutAll:` or `next:` on them. How to communicate with this process?